# Route param only fetching first letter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code. It lets me fetch an image, and specify optionally if a recache is needed. For example, `/something.jpg/force`. It could also be the ID of an image, for example `/7GDF4G`. As you can see, the force param is optional.

```
app.get('/:image/:force?*', function (req, res) {
    console.log("image req");
    // Create variable to hold force bool, default is false
    var force = false;
    // Check if force bool is present
    if (req.params.force === ('force' || 'true' || 'recache' || 're-cache')) {
        force = true;
    }
    // Pass req, res, image variable and force bool to process
    mod.request.process({
        req : req,
        res : res
    }, {
        type : 'image',
        id : req.params.image
    }, force);
});
```

When run, everything is passed onto `mod.request.process()` as expected. However, if I add the following to see what value is being returned for `:image`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This is what is logged:

```
{"type":"image","id":"k"}
```

The input URL was `kMoI9Vn.jpg/force`, so `id` should be `kMoI9Vn.jpg`. If I run it again with `something.jpg`, I get `{"type":"image","id":"s"}`.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Any reason for the asterisk in your route, as that's likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: I got it from the answer to another question, as how to specify an optional route param.

Comment: The asterisk is not needed, remove it and the parameters should work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just remove the asterisk and use just `/:image/:force?`?

This works for both examples:

```
var pathToRegexp = require('path-to-regexp');

var keys = [];
var exp = pathToRegexp('/:image/:force?', keys);
console.dir(exp.exec('/7GDF4G'));
console.dir(exp.exec('/something.jpg/force'));

// outputs:
// [ '/something.jpg/force',
//   'something.jpg',
//   'force',
//   index: 0,
//   input: '/something.jpg/force' ]
// [ '/7GDF4G', '7GDF4G', undefined, index: 0, input: '/7GDF4G' ]
```